# PHP file can't load properly in google chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, xampp

When I open my XAMPP control, then I proceed to my htdocs file where my PHP files is there. I open then this is the result:

[image]

This was working last year and now I don't know what happen since I upgraded my OS to Windows 10.

I tried to change the port, I tried also to change the issue in Skype.
I tried install/uninstall the XAMPP in my laptop. I also changed some config in IIS.
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you've updated your XAMPP install and your old code uses short tags.
Either edit `php.ini` to `short_open_tag=On` or update your code to use `<?php` opening tag